# Limit formatted Measurement to 2 digits

Tags: ios, swift, measurement

I'd like to print a string based on a Measurement but limit it to 2 digits. I am using the **MeasurementFormatter** for this.

```
var beans:Measurement = Measurement(value: 20.22321, unit: UnitMass.milligrams) // "20.22321 mg"
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let label = formatter.string(from: beans) // 0 lb
```

I expected `20.22 mg` as a results, not `0 lb`. Where's my mistake?

Comment: I'm not familiar with measurement but it appears that it's in the wrong units. You want metric units but your formatter doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the `MeasurementFormatter` property `unitOptions` to `.providedUnit`:

```
let beans = Measurement<UnitMass>(value: 20.22321, unit: .milligrams) // "20.22321 mg"
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let label = formatter.string(from: beans) // "20.22 mg"
```