# Zero symbol in iOS MeasurementFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, user-experience, nsnumberformatter, measurementformatter

I'm having problems to declare/use a zero symbol for an unknown value when using `MeasurementFormatter`:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.zeroSymbol = "?"

numberFormatter.string(from: 0.0) // '?'

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
formatter.numberFormatter = numberFormatter

var distance = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 0, unit: .parsecs)
formatter.string(from: distance) // '0 pc' - expected: '? pc'
```

Trying different declarations of the value such as `Double.zero` doesn't change the output.
Is this a conceptual thing in iOS or am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't waste your time fighting against the framework. `distance.value == 0 ?
formatter.string(from: distance).replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: "?") :
formatter.string(from: distance)`.

Comment: btw there is no need to create a number formatter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301418/2303865

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the default decimal formatter! But for the '?" I don't think I'm fighting the system here. What's the purpose of proper formatting, if we have to use string replacements that might even fail in some localization edge cases?

Comment: ops I forgot to replace the zero with ? you can use regex but I don't know if "?" can be localized as well which wouldn't work even when using the number formatter zeroSymbol approach. `replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+", with: "?", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: IMO you shouldn't change the zero symbol at first place. You can simply use an empty string in case of zero values

Comment: Is using '?' a bad practice or conceptually not valid for measurements? I'm more interested in the WHY and not any quick copy/paste solution. If there isn't any clear answer or answers just based on (valid) opinions, I might consider this a bug.

Anyways, many thanks for the time spent so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It turned out](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/417915#417875) to produce the desired output by changing the Measurement declaration (`distance`):

```
let dist1 = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 0, unit: .parsecs) // output: '0 pc'
let dist2 = Measurement(value: 0, unit: Unit(symbol: UnitLength.parsecs.symbol)) // output '? pc' as expected
```

A [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB7685455) is filed.