# Swift MeasurementFormatter incorrectly converting distance to miles

Tags: ios, swift

I have a distance as a double that I wish to display in km. I am trying to use a MeasurementFormatter to format into a string using the code below.
For some reason the formatted string is in miles. The current locale is using metric system.
Does anyone know why this would be? I cannot see any other regional/locale setting which would cause this to happen?
This is in IOS 14

```
func distanceString(for distance: Double) -> String {

    print(Locale.current.usesMetricSystem) //prints true
    let distanceFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    distanceFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    let measurement = Measurement(value: distance, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)

    return distanceFormatter.string(from: measurement)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your current locale?

Comment: Locale is en_GB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the world is not that simple.  Some locales use the metric system, but for historical reasons use miles for distances and speed.  The base English locale (`en`) is one such, while the Australian English locale (`en_au`) uses metric for all measurements including speed and distance.

To get the behaviour you want you do not need to be concerned with the locale.  You are specifying the `Measurement` with a unit of `.kilometers`, so you simply need to set the `.providedUnit` [`unitOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/1642066-unitoptions) on your `MeasurementFormatter` to instruct it to ignore the locale when formatting the measurement:

```
func distanceString(for distance: Double) -> String {

    let distanceFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    distanceFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
    let measurement = Measurement(value: distance, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)

    return distanceFormatter.string(from: measurement)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if thats what is being asked here. I think OP is trying to display the length based on the locale otherwise thats a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301418/2303865

Comment: The first line of the question says "*I have a distance as a double that I wish to display in km*"

Comment: yes but he is setting the formatter locale. I though about suggesting something like `formatter.unitOptions = locale.usesMetricSystem ? .providedUnit : .naturalScale`

Comment: Perhaps, but that wouldn't make a lot of sense; Based on local conventions, people in the UK would expect miles, not km, even though they officially use the metric system.  I think they are setting the locale in attempt to get the desired behaviour of always showing km.

Comment: Yes but I wonder if there is a way to display it properly based on Locale or if it does already work as expected

Comment: Locale `_UK` does print true for metric system so why would it display miles?

Comment: So why `MeasurementFormatter` displays miles?

Comment: Unit is Length not speed

Comment: Because the UK officially uses the metric system for weights and measures since it is/was part of Europe but they use miles for speed and distance for historical reasons.  In the UK road signs and speed limits will show miles but in a shop you will purchase in kg or litres (including fuel)

Comment: I see. `metric`
 makes me think about distance while it is not restricted to that. So returning true doesn't meant it uses metric for all units and therefore Locale.current.usesMetricSystem is kind of ambiguous

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately for some locales, like en_au, “uses metric” is definitive but not for the base “en” locale

Comment: IMO OP should respect the user device locale/region settings (formatters output). provided unit only if the intent is to explicitly show kilometers.

Comment: Yes. We need the OP to confirm their requirements, but based on the first line of the question it was to always show Kilometers.

Comment: Many thanks everyone for all the info and feedback.

Current locale is en_GB so, as @Paul11 says, usesMetricSystem must only apply to weights and measures. I tested this by changing region to Australia and the formatted string displayed in KM.

My intention is to display in KM. While the UK does use miles for road signs, KM is used heavily for measuring pace / distance during excercise. I think this means I will need to override the locale settings.

Thanks for the .providedUnit suggestion. That worked perfectly, I'll accept that answer.

Comment: I had basically the same code as OP and was having the same problem when testing with UK, to see if my "mi" would change to "km". Testing with a local of UK didn't work, but testing with Australia did. I even changed "Measurement System" to Metric in the device settings, with Region set to UK and it still displayed in miles, lol. The accepted answer persuaded me to change my region to Australia and voilà, I'm not getting KM! Thanks everyone!